# apache camel: Dynamic router is calling the same end point for multiple times in a single request

Tags: grails, apache-camel

I have configured the dynamic router in the receiver router like below, 
dynamicRouter(method("com.eg.DynamicIncomingRoute"), "getIncomingRoute"))

But it is redirecting the request for multiple times to the same bean and the same method.

In the logs it shows like this,

### Message History

RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)

[route3            ] [route3            ] [mina2://tcp://localhost:8888?codec=%23hl7codec&sync=true                      ] [     29642]

[route3            ] [dynamicRouter1    ] [dynamicRouter[bean{com.eg.service.handlerService, ] [     29632]

[route1            ] [to1               ] [bean:handlerService?method=handleMessage                     ] [     11835]

[route1            ] [to1               ] [bean:handlerService?method=handleMessage                     ] [     12776]

[route1            ] [to1               ] [bean:handlerService?method=handleMessage                     ] [      4700]

You can observe the route1 is repeated for multiple times. means it is redirecting to the same method for multiple times. Instead i want to send response back to the user. So how can i do that ?

Comment: Worked for me after updating with these lines

public class DynamicRouterBean {
public String route(String body,
@Header(Exchange.SLIP_ENDPOINT) String previous) {
return whereToGo(body, previous);
}
private String whereToGo(String body, String previous) {
if (previous == null) {
return "mock://a";
} else if ("mock://a".equals(previous)) {
return "language://simple:Bye ${body}";
} else {
return null;
}
}
}

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation!

- http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router

See that beware box on that page

Also related is this SO with some details: [Dynamic routing in camel en-queues messages infinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280916/dynamic-routing-in-camel-en-queues-messages-infinitely)